# bundle Less and CSS files together with grails lesscss-resource

Tags: css, grails, less, grails-plugin

In my grails app, I've defined the following resource module that includes a mixture of CSS files generated by Less, and regular CSS files.

```
responsive {
    dependsOn 'jquery'

    resource 'js/responsive/bootstrap.js'

    resource 'css/footer.css'
    resource url: 'less/style.less', attrs: [rel: "stylesheet/less", type: 'css'], bundle: 'bundle_responsive'
}
```

According to the [plugin docs](http://grails.org/plugin/lesscss-resources), `bundle: 'bundle_responsive'` should cause all the CSS files to be bundled together. When the page loads, I see that there is indeed only one CSS bundle

```
<link href="/summer-festivals/bundle-bundle_responsive_head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />
```

However, the bundle file cannot be found, so I get an error:

> ERROR resource.ResourceMeta - Resource not found: /bundle-bundle_responsive_head.css

And of course, none of the resources in the bundle are loaded. If I remove `bundle: 'bundle_responsive'`, all the resources load, but the CSS files generated from Less are in a different bundle to the regular CSS files.

How can I get all CSS files to be bundled together?

Comment: bundle: Must be set as will not default correctly. To add to default bundle use 'bundle_<module name>". It shouldn't be "bundle_responsive" in your case?

Comment: @SérgioMichels the instructions say set it to 'bundle_<module name>' and my module is called 'responsive', so as far as I can tell it *should* be "bundle_responsive" in my case

Comment: Ops, sorry, I thought that was declared as "bundle_style" in the code.

Comment: My suggestion is to change the log level to debug and see if appears more info.

Comment: Why aren't you using `resource url: ''` for your other css and js? I always declare a resource with the url attribute.

Comment: @JamesKleeh because it's completely unnecessary. You only need to specify `url:` if you're also supplying other atributes

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this, so my answer here is given purely based on my reading of the documentation with a comparison of your example code. One difference that may be the cause (you will have to test) is to put your block declaration `responsive` in single quotes like the documentation code, as this *might* be affecting the forming of the "path" to the resource:

Not: `responsive { ... }`

But: `'responsive' { ... }`

Comment: I really can't see anything in the docs that would suggest this will make a difference. Quotes would only be necessary if the module name was a reserved word, e.g. class. But I'll try it out nevertheless - thanks!